# How do I run a Mercurial server?

Tags: mercurial

With Subversion, I used the Visual SVN server to get it up and serving in a few minutes. Is there an equivalent for Mercurial, so I can run hg.mydomain.com?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740075/mercurial-server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for Mercurial server on  Windows, you can get a very good tutorial here: http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/mercurial-on-iis7/ or here: http://blog.schuager.com/2010/03/how-to-setup-mercurial-server-on.html

It's pretty easy to set up and works like a charm.

Answer (score 10):

The [PublishingRepositories](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories) wiki page gives a great overview of all the different ways you can exchange changesets with people.  They range from simple shared files space, to ssh, to the build in `hg serve`, to the hgweb/hgwebdir cgi scripts that came with your mercurial installation.  You need to pick the best mechanism for you, but the hg.yourdomain.com mechanism you describe most closely aligns with the [hgwebdir in Apache solution](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories#multiple) which is fully detailed on the wiki.

Comment: The link is broken - it's been moved to https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories

Answer (score 4):

You can try [HgLab](http://hglabhq.com/): it's a hosted Mercurial server with pull and push support, access control and Active Directory integration.

Comment: It would probably be a great product - if I had a budget for it. :)

Answer (score 3):

Check out the Mercurial wiki on [Publishing Repositories](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories). It contains good information about a variety of different ways to make your repo available across your LAN or the internet. As Pete's comment said, Mercurial has a built-in, quick webserver for working with one or two colleagues on a temporary basis, but that doesn't sound like it would work for your request.

As an aside, I tend to just use <s>BitBucket.org to host my repositories (public and private) and some bug tracking.</s>

---

Update in 2020: They no longer offer Mercurial hosting:

https://bitbucket.org/blog/sunsetting-mercurial-support-in-bitbucket

For a recent list see https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MercurialHosting

---

You may want to look into their plans and weigh that against running your own server. The paid plans allow you to set up CNAMES to point `hg.yourdomain.com` to the BitBucket servers.

Comment: The link is broken - it's been moved to https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories

Answer (score 1):

In 2020 there is heptapod:

https://about.heptapod.host/

They offer paid hosting but you can also download an instance to run it on your own server.

Answer (score 1):

In 2023 there is [SCM-Manager](https://scm-manager.org/) for self hosting git, mercurial, and subversion repositories. It is free and open source. I have had good luck with version 2.20 on Windows. Unfortunately, it is highly version dependent, and not all versions work well.

Answer (score 0):

Mercurial comes with a build in web interface: http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/collaborating-with-other-people.html

Comment: That's hg serve, but it's suitable only for a quick "pull my changes" exchange, not setting up a public facing website.