# Running Mercurial with Apache on Windows XP

Tags: apache, mercurial, windows-xp, hgweb

I've been struggling to get Mercurial working with Apache on Windows XP.

I've read and tried the suggestions at the following SO threads: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229341/mercurial-server-on-apache-windows), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818571/how-to-setup-mercurial-and-hgwebdir-on-iis), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123798/error-setting-up-mercurial-on-windows-server-2008) & [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740075/mercurial-server)

So far all I can is a blank page and when I view the source I can see:

```
<body bgcolor="#f0f0f8"><font color="#f0f0f8" size="-5"> -->
<body bgcolor="#f0f0f8"><font color="#f0f0f8" size="-5"> --> -->
</font> </font> </font> </script> </object> </blockquote> </pre>
</table> </table> </table> </table> </table> </font> </font> </font>
```

What I'm working with:

- Apache 2.2 -- `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\`
- Python 2.4 (as recommended by Mercurial site) -- `C:\Program Files\Python\2.4\`
- Mercurial 1.6 -- `C:\Program Files\Mercurial\`
- `mod_python` 3.3.1
- Apache DocumentRoot: `C:\htdocs\hg\` accessed via `http://hg.paperclip.dev` (added to hosts file)
- Hg Repository (on a networked drive): `H:\repo\`

I have a feel that part of the complication is that I have my repo on a networked drive. Which I can access either through a networked drive letter H or via `\\SERVER\WebDev\repo\`

My `mercurial.ini` in the Mercurial installation directory is as follows:

```
[ui]
editor = Notepad
username = paperclip <p@paperclip.com>
```

My `hgweb.config` in the Hg DocumentRoot served by apache (`C:\htdocs\hg\`)

```
[collections]
//SERVER/WebDev/repo = //SERVER/WebDev/repo**
```

My `hgweb.cgi` in the Hg DocumentRoot serverd by apache (`C:\htdocs\hg\`)

```
#!C:/Program Files/Python/2.4/python.exe

# Path to repo or hgweb config to serve (see 'hg help hgweb')
config = "C:/htdocs/hg/hgweb.config"

# Uncomment and adjust if Mercurial is not installed system-wide:
import sys; sys.path.insert(0, "C:/Program Files/Mercurial/lib")

# Uncomment to send python tracebacks to the browser if an error occurs:
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

from mercurial import demandimport; demandimport.enable()
from mercurial.hgweb import hgweb
from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
application = hgweb(config)
WSGIServer(application).run()
```

My VirtualHosts files for Apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName hg.paperclip.dev
  #ServerAlias paperclip.com *.paperclip.com
  ServerAdmin p@paperclip.com
  CustomLog "logs/hg-access.log" combined
  ErrorLog "logs/hg-error.log"

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule (.*) C:/htdocs/hg/hgweb.cgi/$1

  # Or we can use mod_alias for starting CGI script and making URLs "nice":
  # ScriptAliasMatch ^(.*) C:/htdocs/hg/hgweb.cgi/$1

  <Directory "C:/htdocs/hg/">

    Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
        Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks +Indexes
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi

  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Taking into account the above configuration, I would welcome some suggestions to get this working. Anything I could try as I've hit a total dead end.

Many thanks in advance.

-P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was posted just yesterday:
[Setup Mercurial Server in Windows Machine - Tutorials are outdated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073380/setup-mercurial-server-in-windows-machine-tutorials-are-outdated/7088471#7088471)

This guy managed to get HG + Apache to work on Windows 7.
I know, you're using XP and not Win 7, but maybe this link helps you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Hg 2.0.1

Apache 2.2.21

Python 2.6!

```
#!c:/python26/python.exe
#
# An example hgweb CGI script, edit as necessary
# See also http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories

# Path to repo or hgweb config to serve (see 'hg help hgweb')
#config = "/path/to/repo/or/config"
config = "c:/batch/merc-web.conf"

# Uncomment and adjust if Mercurial is not installed system-wide
# (consult "installed modules" path from 'hg debuginstall'):
#import sys; sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/python/lib")
#import sys; sys.path.insert(0, "c:/mercurial")

# Uncomment to send python tracebacks to the browser if an error occurs:
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

from mercurial import demandimport; demandimport.enable()
from mercurial.hgweb import hgweb, wsgicgi
application = hgweb(config)
wsgicgi.launch(application)
```

forget about mod_python, :81 is IIS on my machine and apache is on 80 and 91, so http://ap.xxx.tzo.net/cgi-bin/hgweb.cgi works

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName ap.xxx.tzo.net
ServerAlias ap.xxx.tzo.net

ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://localhost:91/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:91/
<Proxy http://localhost:91/>
#  Order Allow,Deny
#  Allow from all
   Order Deny,Allow
   Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

also envvar PYTHONPATH C:\Python26

I realize you are on different version of HG etc, but I hope this helps.
I think it took me 2 days ;)

Try with a local repo, your mercurial.ini is N/A. My merc-web.conf looks like:

```
[web]
style = coal

[paths]
/hgAppThree = C:\!mark\_dev\hgAppThree
```

which applies like

http://ap.xxx.tzo.net/cgi-bin/hgweb.cgi/hgAppThree

Good luck!